# How to replace a value of variable with different different values using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have this:

```
"KeySchema" : [
      {
        "AttributeName" : "id",
        "KeyType" : "HASH"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName" : "chunk_id",
        "KeyType" : "RANGE"
      }
    ],
    "ProvisionedThroughput" : {
      "ReadCapacityUnits" :  "20",
      "WriteCapacityUnits" : "10"
    },
    "TableName" : "uat_appcast"
```

I want to change the value of "TableName" which is "uat_appcast" with another value say "qa_appcast_01"

I have got multiple instances of "TableName" in this file and each will have different value.

Comment: If it has a different value every time than you can't (easily) do that in Notepad++. It might be possible using the Python plugin.

Comment: just curious but if these are key value pairs and you have multiple instances for the key "TableName" then how would your language know / how would you specify,  which you want?